# Почему не проходит HQL запрос?

Tags: java, hibernate

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что здесь не так? Хочу извлечь salary,subject, FirstName данные три поля, при том, что salary>500, но получаю Exception вида

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: by near line 1, column 76 [select e.salary,e.FirstName,m.subject
```

Не могли бы вы объяснить что я делаю не так?

```
List list1;

Query query1 = session.createQuery("select e.salary,e.FirstName,m.subject from Employee e,Meeting m where e.salary>500");

list1 = query1.list();

log.info("=====");

list1.stream().forEach(emplSalary -> log.info(emplSalary.toString()));
```

Сущность Employee:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "IMPLOYEE_ID", unique = true)
private Long employeeID;
private String FirstName;
private String LastName;
private int salary;

@ToString.Exclude
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
private EmployeeDetail employeeDetail;
@ToString.Exclude
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
private Department department;

@ToString.Exclude
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "EMPLOYEE_MEETING", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "MEETING_ID")})
private List<Meeting> meetings = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

Сущность Meeting:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEETING")
public class Meeting {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "MEETING_ID")
private Long meetingID;
private String subject;
private LocalDateTime startDate;

@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "meetings")
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();

public Meeting(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
    this.startDate = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

}

Comment: добавьте в вопрос сущности

Comment: Внес изменения.

Comment: Скорее всего, у Вас поле   FirstName в БД через подчерк ( First_Name ) и необходимо поставить аннотацию @Column(name = "first_name")